# Review the css and theme also like we do for code using code review module

Tags: 7

To check my code in custom module we use [Code Review](http://drupal.org/project/coder) module.   Is there a similar module for themes and CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by the 'Code Review module' you mean the [Coder](http://drupal.org/project/coder) module, it already supports reviewing the code in themes.

> Beginning with the 5.x-2.x version, this module adds a new UI, core
>   support, theme support, and a cache for faster display of unchanged
>   files. It also supports rule #severity levels of "minor", "normal",
>   and "critical."